# Javascript conditional empty string

Tags: javascript, validation, date, conditional-statements

I would like to validate a date (passed in arg as a string formatted like 99/99/9999). For my needs, empty/null/undefined string should be considered as good.

---

Here is my validation function:

```
function isDateValid(date) {
    if(date && date.length == 0){
        return true;
    }
    //more checks
}
```

---

I got strange results, that I can't explain:

- With a empty string (string with 0 char length) the condition is evaluated to an empty String and therefore don't reach the `return true`
- With a filled string (ex: "01/01/2018") the condition is evaluated to a `false` boolean.

I know how to change to make the code run as I need.... but this makes me sick to understand why this has 2 different comportement (once string, once boolean).

I need a captain here!

---

Adding some `console.log` as

```
function isDateValid(date) {
    console.log(date);
    console.log(date.length);
    console.log(date && date.length == 0);
    console.log(typeof (date && (date.length == 0)));
    if(date && date.length == 0){
        return true;
    }
    //more...
}
```

will produce the following output:

[image: with 01/01/2018]
[image: with empty string]

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v8easudj/2/

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproduction within a fiddle? What are the input and expected output...

Comment: here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/v8easudj/2/

Comment: @phuzi just posted an answer that explain you a little bit more about what is "falsy". An empty string for instance is falsy. I updated your jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v8easudj/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answers stated, JavaScript has a notion of truthy and falsy values -- i.e. values that are implicitly considered `true` or `false` when you use them as booleans (like in `if` statements or with conditional operators).

In particular, empty strings are falsy.

---

In your case, you get a different `typeof`, because the `&&` boolean operator gets short-circuited on a falsy value. It stops further evaluation and returns the left operand.

So you feed in an empty string, `&&` stops there and you get the `typeof` of what's on the left -- i.e. of the empty string.

You feed in a non-empty string, `&&` proceeds and you get the `typeof` of its right operand -- i.e of the *boolean* result of `date.length == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has a notion of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) [coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion) so "" (empty string), null and undefined (as well as a few others) are falsey, so

```
if (!date)
    return true;
```

Will simultaneously check if date is null, undefined or an empty string and return true.

For more information check out the articles on MDN

- [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)
- [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)
- [Type Conversion/Coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion)

Comment: Well documented answer but as the answer of @Lyosha Korogoda explains well why the comportment is different in my case, I will accept his answer.